# Elevated camera look at point

Tags: javascript, 3d, camera, three.js

I'm rotating a sphere around the z-axis and want an elevated camera to look down at this sphere. Unfortunately the camera is 'unstable' and making me seasick. How do I prevent this wave motion in the camera?

The code to move and look at the sphere is in the animate method of this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjtffr02/).

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    var timer = Date.now() * 0.0009;
    sphere.position.x = Math.sin(timer) * 3000;
    sphere.position.y = Math.cos(timer) * 3000;
    camera.lookAt(sphere.position);
    render();
}
```

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/kjtffr02/2/

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunatly not. What I want is the camera to keep looking at the horizon, but without tilting the way it is now.

Answer (score 1):

For camera to keep looking at the horizon, as you said, you must use an Object3D I think:

```
obj = new THREE.Object3D(); // use object so that rotation is relative to this
obj.add(sphere);
sphere.position.y = 3000; // distance from origin
scene.add(obj);    // add object, no sphere
```

Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/kjtffr02/4/

Comment: Thank you. I thought this was working, but it's only because you changed camera.rotateX(Math.PI / 2.7) to camera.rotateX(Math.PI / 2). If you change it back the rotation is all weird again. I would like it to work with the  camera.lookAt if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you reverse the axis and because the camera when and reaches 180 degrees makes a turn when it is on the y axis but but when reversing this we avoid the strange rotation of the camera.

[Here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/canvas_camera_orthographic.html#LC152)   is the code of an example (look at the function **render()**) and [here](https://threejs.org/examples/canvas_camera_orthographic) is the demo.